# Is there a way to change notification title when user expend notification?

Tags: android, notifications, android-4.2-jelly-bean

My question is pretty much said in the title. I'm working with Android's bigText notification style. I have changed the text content when user expend the notification, but I haven't found a way to also change notification title.    Is there a callback I can listen for?

Thanks to CRUSADER, `bigContentTitle()` works great!

Comment: check [for ref](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html). it also contains sample for the same.

Comment: Wow @CRUSADER I think bigContentTitle may be what I am looking for! Let me give it a shot.

Comment: @CRUSADER please make this as an answer and I will accept it.

Comment: [check for ref](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications.html) link . It also contains **sample** for the same.

Comment: Added in answer section

Answer (score 1):

There is no such callback. Whatever you provide in the `Notification` is what is shown. You cannot change the title except by re-raising the `Notification`, and you have no way to know when to do that in this case.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I am afraid as well.

Comment: @Patrick: CRUSADER's `bigContentTitle` suggestion should solve your problem, assuming that you only needed to have a different title from the normal style `Notification`.